# OpenERP how project phase team members can view only their phases?

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP, I have found that it is possible to record a rule so project team members can only see their projects with the following rule definition in settings -> security -> record -rules on the project.project model:

['|',('members','in', [user.id]),('user_id','=',user.id)]

My question is how it would be possible to record a similar rule for the "team planning" feature on project.phase model?
The above code does not work for this, but can it be modified?
Or is there another way to restrict the access to project phases to only those who has been assigned to the phase or project?

Kind Regards

Johan

Comment: you found any answer till now?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this record rule on object(project.user.allocation)  Phase User Allocation,

```
['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]
```

Created a new rule for this object

Hope this will help